# ORA-04063: package body "WB_PROD.PLOG" has errors

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-04063

I developing asp.net site with oracle back end
I imported data from .dmp file to local db and connected to the db from the web application.

When i run the application im getting following error

```
ORA-04063: package body "WB_PROD.PLOG" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "WB_PROD.PLOG"
ORA-06512: at "WB_PROD.WB_PCK_LOG", line 85
ORA-06512: at "WB_PROD.WB_PCK_USERS", line 133
ORA-04063: package body "WB_PROD.PLOG" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "WB_PROD.PLOG"
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Please let me know how to solve this issue....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved issues by seeing errors as Justin Cave said. For any one who have the same issue, i run following scripts to solve issue

```
SQL> connect / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> grant execute on dbms_pipe to wb_prod;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant execute on sys.dbms_system to wb_prod;

Grant succeeded.
```

Which solved problem.

Answer (score 7):

The package body PLOG in the schema WB_PROD apparently does not exist or does not compile.  You can try to compile it.  Connect to the database as the WB_PROD user and issue the command

```
SQL> alter package body plog compile;
```

If there are errors,

```
SQL> show errors
```

Comment: yes im seeing errors, mainly i see two errors--- Error(275,9): PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_PIPE' must be declared and Error(289,9): PLS-00201: identifier 'SYS.DBMS_SYSTEM' must be declared. Thanks

Comment: i solved issues by seeing the errors. Thank you for kind to reply

Answer (score 4):

There is a syntax error mentioned in the answer above.

In `11g2` you have to write:

```
SQL> alter package plog compile body;
```

If there are errors:

```
SQL> show errors;
```